# Git svn fetch and then commit to remote git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

My customer has a  SVN repo and I would like to use git on my side instead. I used git-svn to create a git from my customer's svn and created a gitlab for it. If my customer changes something on his side I would like to fetch the changes and then update my gitlab to keep everything in sync.

Currently I'm using:

```
git svn fetch
```

And if something was changed, I get a few changes. After receiving the changes I am still not able to push said changes to my git.

```
git commit -am "Changed something"
```

returns:

> Your branch is up-to-date with xxx
>
> nothing to commit, working directory clean

Clearly something changed but my git won't notice.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### tl;dr

If you want to keep your GitLab repository in sync with the Subversion one, you should run these commands:

```
# Fetch the latest commits from SVN and merge them into the current branch
git svn rebase

# Push the new commits to GitLab
git push origin
```

### Background

Logically speaking, when you run `git svn fetch` you're receiving new *commits* from the SVN repository – not files.

That's why you're getting that error message when you try to create a new commit: Git is telling you that you don't have any modified files in your working directory.

`git svn fetch` will download the new commits into your repository but it *won't automatically merge them* into the current branch. To do that, you should run:

```
git svn rebase
```

Here's what the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion#Pulling-in-New-Changes) has to say about it:

> You can run `git svn fetch` to grab the new data, but `git svn rebase`
>   does the fetch and then updates your local commits.

Keep in mind that you shouldn't have any modified files in your working directory when you run `git svn rebase`:

> You need to be sure your working directory is clean when you run this,
>   though. If you have local changes, you must either stash your work or
>   temporarily commit it before running `git svn rebase` — otherwise, the
>   command will stop if it sees that the rebase will result in a merge
>   conflict.

After the commits have been fetched and merged, you can publish them to your GitLab repository by saying:

```
git push origin
```

where `origin` is the name of the remote that points to the GitLab repository.

Comment: Sounds right. Unfortunately after trying around to much before your answer I now don't get any changes when using "git svn rebase" but also can't push anything to my gitlab. No changes... but I know there have to be... As soon as I get it to work I'll mark this answer as correct

Comment: Had to do a reset to an earlier revision to fix the problem. Used "git svn info" to get the newest revision my git svn has. I then used said revision - 1 for "git svn reset -p xxxx". After that I could use "git svn rebase" and "git push" as you said. Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation of git svn fetch vs git svn rebase has answered a long outstanding question for me!  If you ultimately need to use git svn rebase to actually use the changes from svn, why would anyone ever use git svn fetch? What is the purpose of having those commits?